# Convert XML requests to JSON on the fly using AWS lambda function and Application load balancer (ALB)

Tags: json, xml, rest, aws-lambda

I am working on an integration with a Vendor that can only send me XML requests in a predefined structure
That is not compatible with my system. 
Changing the structure of the XML is possible but might be an expensive project if the Vendor would do it for me.

To try and solve this issue i was wondering, would it be possible to convert the said XML requests to JSON on the fly using an AWS Lambda function? 
I was thinking about a solution in which an XML requests comes in from the Vendor to my ALB, converted to a JSON request using a Lambda function and returned to my system for processing in a JSON format. 
Would this be a scalable solution?

Comment: When you get XML that is "not compatible with your system", this implies that other XML would be compatible. Wouldn't it make sense to change the XML into compatible XML, instead of into JSON?

Comment: You are basically correct but considering the structure of the XML request of the vendor it looks very similar to the structure of a JSON request does is supported by my system.
I tried converting the XML request to a JSON format using an online tool. 
The JSON output was 95% compatible and required some additional minor adjustments.
I suspect that changing the vendor XML request to be compatible with my system's XML format might be more difficult than converting the XML to JSON

Comment: There is a very well-working, widely-supported, standard tool available to transform XML into a different shape - XSLT. It might be easier to use this instead of converting data to an inferior format with non-standard tools.

Comment: I thought about using XSLT
The questions is how do you use this method at scale to change the XML request structure on the fly?
Will you still use a lambda function? 
Will using XSLT give you better performance?

Comment: As with all performance questions, you will have to test if you want to know the answer for your use case. XSLT can be of course be done on AWS. An example using Java+Saxon here https://github.com/AtomGraph/XSLTTransform, via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48573619/, but XSLT can be done in other languages the platform supports, e.g. with the lxml library in Python, natively in C#, and so on. There are a few variants available to try.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible here is a solution in `Node.js`
You will need the `xml-js` npm  package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js

`package.json`

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "xml-js": "^1.6.11"
},
...
```

`index.js`

```
const toJSON = xml => JSON.parse(xmljson.xml2json(xml, { compact: true, spaces: 0 }));
```

And then you can simply return `toJSON(xml)`.